# Cant get values from mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I have a MongoDB API return in node js.

In the database I have values but I can't retrieve it with the API.

My model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true)


const plannerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
         type: String,
         required: true
     },
    task: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdat: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('planner', plannerSchema);
```

My code

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const PlannerSchema = require('../models/planner');

router.post('/get', async(req, res) => {
    let email = req.body.email

    try {
        const tasks = PlannerSchema.find({email:email})
        if(tasks){
            res.status(200).json({
                message:"success",
                content:tasks
            })
        } else {
            res.status(200).send('empty')
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send('error-occurred')
    }
})
```

I always get the response as error-occurred.

Please give me a solution

Thanks in advace

Comment: Can you add the line `console.log(error)` inside the catch block? It will display the error that is occuring while trying to find the documents from MongoDB.

Comment: ok I will try it out

Comment: Also `PlannerSchema.find({email:email})` is an asynchronous operation. It would be advisable to use `await` in that statement to synchronously work with DB queries. So you may change the `tasks` declaration to `const tasks = await PlannerSchema.find({email:email})`

Comment: ok I will try it out

Comment: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
    --- property 'topology' closes the circle
This is my error mesage

Comment: The error refers to your `MongoDB Connection`. It would be a good idea if you can update the question with the code-snippet where you have specified your mongodb connection using mongoose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const PlannerSchema = require('../models/planner');

router.post('/get', async (req, res) => {
    let email = req.body.email;

    try {
        const tasks = await PlannerSchema.find({
            email: email
        }) // use await here
        if (tasks) {
            res.status(200).json({
                message: "success",
                content: tasks
            });
        } else {
            res.status(200).send('empty');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error); //to print error on terminal
        res.status(400).send('error-occurred');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`PlannerSchema.find({email:email})` is asynchronous so use `await` keyword. And `find` method is deprecated in MongoDB so better to use `findOne`. As per the ES6 version if key and value are the same then you can use the only `email` instead of `email:email`. So your code finally will be

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const PlannerSchema = require('../models/planner');

router.post('/get', async (req, res) => {
    let email = req.body.email;

    try {
         //changes here
        const tasks = await PlannerSchema.findOne({email})
        if (tasks) {
            res.status(200).json({
                message: "success",
                content: tasks
            });
        } else {
            res.status(200).send('empty');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error); //to print error on terminal
        res.status(400).send('error-occurred');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **then()** instead of await like below:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const PlannerSchema = require('../models/planner');

router.post('/get', async(req, res) => {
    let email = req.body.email

    try {
        const tasks = PlannerSchema.find({email:email}).then((doc)={
         if(doc){
            res.status(200).json({
                message:"success",
                content:tasks
            })
          } else {
            res.status(200).send('empty')
          }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send('error-occurred')
    }
})
```